# Как преобразовать вектор с n координат в 2-д вектор?

Tags: python

Допустим, имеется 2 вектора:
`(10,10, 0)`, `(-10, 10, 0)`, требуется преобразовать их в такие двухмерные векторы, чтобы сохранить расстояние между ними. Например, в данном случае, Евклидово расстояние между этими векторами равно: `20`, тогда новые векторы должны быть: `(10, 0), (30, 0)` (т.к расстояние между ними так же равно 20)

Очевидно, что может быть бесконечное количество решений, поэтому условимся, что расстояние от центра координат до данных векторов должно быть равно расстоянию от центра координат до выходных векторов. А так же, расстояние от произвольной точки А (выбираем до всех вычислений) до входного вектора, должно быть таким же, как расстояние от точки А до выходного вектора.

Нужен алогоритм, который может на вход принять n-ое количество векторов с любым кол-вом координат (например, вектор `(10, -10, 5, 4, 15, 16, 0, -3, -12, 5)`), а на выходе должны получаться двухмерные векторы. Расстояние между входными и выходными векторами должно быть одинаковым.

Возможно ли вообще реализовать подобное с минимальной погрешностью?

Comment: Возможно, на ваш вопрос быстрее ответят здесь https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Пусть нам даны вектора А=( а1, ..., an)? и B=(b1, ..., bn), наши многомерные вектора, поданные на вход, расстояние между которыми равно L. Тогда, что нам мешает сказать, пусть вектор B имеет координаты (bx,by)(взять произвольные числа)  и тогда нам надо будет решить уравнение sqrt( (ax-bx)^2 + (ay-by)^2 ) = L, т.е. нам надо будет найти пару чисел (ax,ay). Если возвести это в квадрат, то мы получим  (ax-bx)^2 + (ay-by)^2 = L^2, а это уже уравнение окружности с радиусом L и центром в точке (bx, by). Я не могу себя назвать сильным математиком, поэтому не знаю можно ли так сделать

Comment: Vetedde, вы правы, решений тут получается бесконечное количество. Дополнил тему некоторыми условиями, т.к это не совсем тот случай.

Comment: А почему накладывается такое условие? Т.е. почему мы не можем из бесконечного множетсва решений взять любую пару? Если не секрет, это формализация какой-то практической задачи или абстрактный вопрос?

Comment: Vetedde, в случае если мы будет решать задачу таким образом, мы получим решение именно для этих двух векторов, но нужна функция, которая сможет принимать n-количество векторов (10, 1000, 10000 и тд) и расстояние между выходными векторами будет такое же, как расстояние между входными. Сейчас дополню тему.

Comment: И возможно я задам глупый вопрос, но как между векторами (10,10, 0), (-10, 10, 0) получилось евклидово расстояние 28.28427? Вы вычисляли по этой формуле(см. ссылку)? Или я что-то не так поняла?https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Да, ошибся, момент

Comment: т.е. у вас может быть и разное количество векторов и произвольная размерность векторов, правильно? Тут в теории можно взять за основу одну пару векторов(А и В), задать координаты для В, вычислить как описанно выше А, потом взять пару А и С, вычислить для С и т.д. А точнее вообще составить систему. Но не думаю, что это самое элегантное решение

Comment: А вы уверены, что можно расположить группу векторов таким образом, чтобы и расстояния между ними сохранялись при переходе, и расстояния от них до начала координат сохранялось? Кстати выбор точки отсчета тоже вещи произвольная, в теории можно найти группу векторов, а затем просто перенести начало координат в нужную точку

Comment: В общем по сути надо аккуратно составить систему и решить ее, я попробую довести идею до конца. Или найду ошибку, или попробую решить, если что-то получится, напишу=)

Comment: Спасибо, буду тоже пробовать по вашей идее :)

Comment: Только оговорюсь, что велосипед=) уверена, нашли уже или в линале или в ангеме какое-нибудь преобразование, но я его, увы, не знаю(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128073/discussion-between-vetedde-and-bleno).